# JanusGraph OOM Exception w/ High Degree Vertex

Tags: out-of-memory, janusgraph

This is a question regarding a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` issue observed while executing operations against JanusGraph.

#### Setup

I am running JanusGraph version `0.2.0` with Cassandra as the underlying storage. I am using default configuration values as described [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/config-ref.html), except for configuration describing my storage backend as `cql` and the storage host.

I'm inserting a large list of users into the graph - each one has (1) an email, (2) a user ID, and (3) an associated grouping label. For this scenario, all the users are in the same grouping, that we'll call `groupA`.
The inserts are done sequentially, each executed immediately after the previous completes.

During each insert operation, I create one vertex representing the email, one vertex representing the user ID, then create or update the vertex representing `groupA`. I create an edge between (1) the email <-> userID vertex, and an edge between (2) the userID <-> `groupA` vertex.

#### Observed Problem

I used a profiler to observe the heap space usage during the process. The insertions ran without a problem in the beginning, but as more insertions were made, the heap space used increased. Eventually, as more memory was used, I reached an out of memory exception after running for several hours.

--

I then repeated the insertions a second time, but this time I did not include the `groupA` vertex. This time, the memory usage showed a standard sawtooth pattern over time as shown below.

[image: Heap Usage with Group Vertex Removed from Insertions]

This leads me to conclude that the out of memory issues I observed were due to operations involving this high degree `groupA` vertex.

#### Potential Leads

I currently suspect that there is some caching process on JanusGraph which stores recently accessed elements. Since the adjacency list of the high degree group vertex is large, then there may be large amounts of data cached, that only increases as I create more and more edges from the group vertex to user ID vertices.

Using my profiler, I noticed that there was a relatively high memory usage by the `org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationCache` class, so this seems to be relevant.

#### My Question

My question is: what is the cause of this increasingly high memory usage over time with JanusGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Consider frequent commits. When you insert data, they are held in the transaction cache till the transaction is committed. Also, take a look at your configuration for the db cache. You will find more information about the cache [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/caching.html).